# Midi Program not sending notes

Tags: arduino-pro-micro, midi

I'm working on a midi device with a pro micro, it's reading as a midi device, but not outputting any notes, here's my program: 
    const int button1 = 2;
    const int button2 = 3;
    const int button3 = 4;
    const int button4 = 5;
    const int button5 = 6;
    const int button6 = 7;

```
int note = 0;

const int c3 = 36;
const int d3 = 38;
const int e3 = 40;
const int f3 = 41;
const int g3 = 43;
const int a3 = 45;

void setup() {

  pinMode(button1,INPUT);
  pinMode(button2,INPUT);
  pinMode(button3,INPUT);
  pinMode(button4,INPUT);
  pinMode(button5,INPUT);
  pinMode(button6,INPUT);

  Serial.begin(31250);

}

void loop() {
  int button1State = digitalRead(button1);
  int button2State = digitalRead(button2);
  int button3State = digitalRead(button3);
  int button4State = digitalRead(button4);
  int button5State = digitalRead(button5);
  int button6State = digitalRead(button6);

  if (button1State == HIGH) {
    note = c3;
    noteOn(0x90, note, 0x64);
  }
  if (button1State == LOW) {
    note = c3;
    noteOn(0x90, note, 0x00);
  }

  if (button2State == HIGH) {
    note = d3;
    noteOn(0x90, note, 0x64);
  }
  if (button2State == LOW) {
    note = d3;
    noteOn(0x90, note, 0x00);
  }

  if (button3State == HIGH) {
    note = e3;
    noteOn(0x90, note, 0x64);
  }
  if (button3State == LOW ) {
    note = e3;
    noteOn(0x90, note, 0x00);
  }

  if (button4State == HIGH) {
    note = f3;
    noteOn(0x90, note, 0x64);
  }
  if (button4State == LOW) {
    note = f3;
    noteOn(0x90, note, 0x00);
  }

  if (button5State == HIGH) {
    note = g3;
    noteOn(0x90, note, 0x64);
  }
  if (button5State == LOW) {
    note = g3;
    noteOn(0x90, note, 0x00);
  }

  if (button6State == HIGH) {
    note = a3;
    noteOn(0x90, note, 0x64);
  }
  if (button6State == LOW ) {
    note = a3;
    noteOn(0x90, note, 0x00);
  }

}

void noteOn(int cmd, int pitch, int velocity) {
  Serial.write(cmd);
  Serial.write(pitch);
  Serial.write(velocity);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are handling your buttons in completely the wrong way. You are basically saying:

> While I press this button send a constant stream of NOTE ON commands. Otherwise send a constant stream of NOTE OFF commands.
>
> At the same time, send more NOTE OFF commands because the other buttons aren't pressed.

So you can see it's going to be a bit of a mess.

Instead you need to detect *changes* in the state of a button.

For example:

```
void loop() {
    static bool oldButton1 = LOW;

    bool button1State = digitalRead(button1);

    if (button1State != oldButton1) { // It changed from last time
        oldButton1 = button1State; // Remember it for next time
        if (button1State) { // Pressed
            noteOn(0x90, c3, 0x64); 
        } else { // Released
            noteOn(0x80, c3, 0x00); // Note: 0x80 is NOTE OFF, not 0x90.
        }
    }

    ... etc for the other buttons ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check:

- If your serial properties are ok (baudrate 31250, 8 bits, 1 stop bit)
- Check if noteOn is really called (print out the values which are sent)
- Show your MIDI circuit, assuming you think no MIDI notes are send because you have a MIDI connector attached.
- Use a protocol analyzer if you have one to check the MIDI signals sent
- Check the components of your circuit, e.g. if you use an opto-coupler, what types is it? some are too slow for MIDI
- Do not use virtual serial ports, I tried with MIDI and they give bad results (checked on Uno).